# Ansible. Uninstall Windows Program

Tags: ansible, winrm

I'm trying to remove the program in Windows 10 via Ansible. The connection is configured, the client is available and pings. The task passes without errors, but nothing happens, the program is still in place.
I assume that the problem lies in the access rights, although I have already created the right user, I do not care. The program was previously installed not via Ansible but by a local user.

If you delete it manually and set it from scratch through Ansible, that's fine.

I will be very grateful for the help.

```
  ---
- name: Test Uninstall LibreOffice 6.0.4.2
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Uninstall Libre
      win_chocolatey:
        name: libreoffice-fresh
        state: absent


PLAY [Test Uninstall LibreOffice 6.0.4.2] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.16.12.174]

TASK [Uninstall Libre] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.16.12.174]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
172.16.12.174              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Is it really an Ansible problem? Does Chocolatey uninstall the package properly? Read also: https://superuser.com/q/789190/493903

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the program installed through chocolatey?

You can try this

```
tasks:
- name: Uninstall Libre
  win_shell: Get-AppxPackage <app name> | Remove-AppxPackage
```

If you're not sure how Windows names the app, you can try the command

```
$ Get-AppxPackage
```

In powershell, and it'll show you all the downloaded apps.